# Distribution of the product of Gaussian column matrix and Signed Bernoulli matrix

Tags: probability-distributions

This is not a homework question though it might be trivial for those who are well versed with multivariate distributions. I am trying to understand a paper that has the following product form.
Let $A$ be a row matrix that has only single entry picked from a Gaussian distribution and rest of them are zero.
Let $H$ be a Walsh-Hadamard matrix and $B$ be a diagonal signed Bernoulli matrix with parameter $p=1/2$.
Let $x$ be a unit vector.

What is the probability distribution of $AHBx$?

Comment: Which paper? $ $

Comment: It's okay, I figured it out. The paper appeared in ICML last year.

Comment: "I figured it out" = you solved the question? This is nice, then you might want to post yourself a solution and even, after a while, to accept it.